# How to disable usage of Cipher at OS level?

Tags: operating-system, tls1.2

I want to disable usage of: 
  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 
  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 
  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 
  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

I went though this: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245030/how-to-restrict-the-use-of-certain-cryptographic-algorithms-and-protoc

I tried something like:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes

Adding DWORD SHA384 to 0x0

But found it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto).

Click on Chiper Suites and disable the chipers you want. You'll be prompted to restart after click aplly.

[image]